# gulp mix.sass doesn't output map file (laravel-elixir)

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I need .map file of style.sass. I tried to run "gulp" by terminal but there is no .map file output on 'resources/assets/stylesheets' 
     This is my code in gulpfile.js. I tried to set both    "elixir.config.sourcemaps = true;" and "elixir.extend('sourcemaps', true);" but it's still not working.

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task("default",function(){
    elixir(function(mix) {
        mix.sass('app.scss', 'public/stylesheets/');
        mix.sass('../stylesheets/style.sass', 'resources/assets/stylesheets');

        mix.copy('resources/assets/fonts/**', 'public/fonts/');
        mix.copy('resources/assets/images/**', 'public/images/');
        mix.copy('resources/assets/javascripts/**', 'public/javascripts/');
        mix.copy('resources/assets/stylesheets/*.css', 'public/stylesheets/');
    });
})
```